# Is Kim Jong UN a space alien according to new NASA evidence?

Tags: aliens, nasa, north-korea

According to [*Sunday Sport* newspapper](http://www.pressreader.com/uk/sunday-sport/20170521/281496456221829) (front page from 21st May 2017), based on recently leaked top secret documents and conclusion from a top NASA and Pentagon suggests that 'Kim is an ET sent as an "advance guard" to destabilise the planet ahead of a full-scale invasion from outer space'.

> The report, entitled "Possible extra-terrestrial origin of North Korea high command", states that analysts have been examing the appearance and behaviour of Kim, 32, and several of his top North Korean generals.

I've tried to search, but I couldn't find such report.

How reliable is that information? Is Kim Jong UN really a space alien?

[image: Sunday Sport, Kim Jong UN is a space alien]

[image: Sunday Sport, Kim Jong UN is a space alien, front page]

Picture of Kim's space tongue (provided evidence):

[image: Sunday Sport, Kim's space tongue]

Comment: Anyone that actually believes this story isn't going to be convinced by any facts we can present here.

Comment: The Sunday Sport isn't a newspaper as such. It printed obviously made up rubbish. I belive the US equivalent is the National Enquirer, only rather further divorced from reality. Other Sunday Sport headlines I can remember include "London bus found on the moon"  and "astronomers discover entrance to heaven just beyond orbit of Pluto". I.e. This isn't a notable claim because no-one could possibly take anything in that publication seriously.

Comment: I'm not at all convinced this is notable. Do many people believe the outlandish headlines in Sunday Sport?

Comment: I've added picture of Kim's space tongue as extra evidence, hope that helps.

Comment: Pretty sure most readers of such papers know it's a spoof paper.

Comment: The Sunday Sport is a humoristic newspaper, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunday_Sport

Comment: @PhillS The US equivalent was Weekly World News, but it is now an online-only publication.

Comment: @PhillS About a year ago I'd have agreed, but people took the "Pizzagate" story seriously *despite the pizza place not even **having** a basement*. And people still believe it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> How reliable is that information?

Not reliable at all. The  [Sunday Sport wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunday_Sport) entry says as much:

> *...It prints plainly ludicrous stories, such as "London Bus Found Frozen In Antarctic Ice", or "World War II Bomber Found On The Moon". Defenders of the paper pointed out that it was not intended to be taken seriously.*

They may have a wide audience, but it's more for entertainment reasons and not because they're a reliable lens with which to view the world.

Comment: To be fair, "The Onion" is openly satirical, while the Sport and Enquirer don't actually admit their stories are false.

Comment: [National Enquirer broke John Edwards story](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Edwards_extramarital_affair#Initial_National_Enquirer_allegations) when most left leaning mass media was ignoring (or suppressing) it. So your answer seems to mean the alien thing actually can be for realz.

Comment: Can anyone prove that a WW2 bomber wasn't found on the moon, or that Elvis doesn't live in it?  Until they can I don't think people should be so dismissive of the best newspaper in the UK.  I almost managed to type that with a straight face :)